# Saving an h2o pipeline model build using sklearn

Tags: scikit-learn, save, pipeline, h2o, pre-trained-model

I have an sklearn pipeline with h2o preprocessors and h2o estimators. Please see below.

```
pipeline = Pipeline([("standardize", h2o.transforms.preprocessing.H2OScaler()),
                     ("pca", h2o.transforms.decomposition.H2OPCA(k=2)),
                     ("drf", h2o.estimators.random_forest.H2ORandomForestEstimator(ntrees=200))])
pipeline.fit(iris_df[:4],iris_df[4])
```

I am unable to save this pipeline model in any way described in the h2o documentation. I have tried POJO, MOJO, pickle, dill etc.

Please help me in solving this issue. It would be helpful for me, if I could save the model using pickle.

Thanks,
Anup.